# Blazor PWA can't call .net framework dlls

Tags: c#, dll, progressive-web-apps, blazor

I have dlls written in .NET Framework 4.6.1 and I am trying to include them in a new Blazor PWA project. I added two of these dlls as project references to the PWA project and able to write code and compile successfully. But whenever a call is made to these Dlls, I always get a null ref exception.

Specifically:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there any trick to successfully adding reference dlls and calling them?

Thanks

Comment: Your dlls should be able to target netstandard2.1 in order to work on the given app.

Comment: There can be none. Blazor is initially backed by a Mono based profile, and soon .NET 5. However, it is never going to support the .NET Framework based profile. Your only option is to migrate your dlls to .NET Standard.

Comment: Because Blazor can run on Windows, Linux and Mac it cannot support libraries that only run on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. As you guys pointed out, I moved to .net standard for those DLLs and the problem seems to have disappeared.